# how to index a subsection of a 2D array python

Tags: python, numpy

I have large arrays of dict structures, say 3000x4000.  I need to be able to set a subsection of the array to a given value.

My array is set up as this:

```
G = np.ndarray((2,int(3000),int(4000)),dtype=[('C',int),('R',int),('G',int)])
```

For example, I want to set a dict value in columns from 0 to 20 and rows from 40-50 to 1.

I am trying this:

```
G[0][0:20,40:50]['G'] = 1
```

But it is not working.  What is the easiest and most efficient way to do this in numpy?

Iterating over the values is possible but I thought numpy had faster methods of indexing

Comment: `for i in range(0, 20):
    for j in range(40, 50):
        G[i][j]['G'] = 1
`

Comment: What is a `dict structure`?  A structured array?  Or an object dtype array with dictionary elements?  Give us a small example (e.g. a (3,4) array) so it is clear.

Comment: It's working actually! Just try printing `G[0][0:20,40:50]['G']`.